# Div tag nesting when using single tag

Tags: html, behavior

So I have the following html:

```
    <html>
<head>
    <style>
        .box
        {
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
        }       
        #box1
        {
            background-color: Red;
        }
        #box2
        {
            background-color: Red;
        }
        #box3
        {
            border-style: dotted;
        }
        #box4
        {
            background-color: Red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="box1" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box2" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box3" class="box"></div>
    <div id="box4" class="box"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I change any of the div tags to their single tag version, for example:

```
<div id="box1" class="box"/>
```

the subsequent tags become nested, at least in Chrome, Firefox and IE. Does anyone know the deal regarding this behavior? It seems like a bug to me.

Comment: strange, nothing here suggests that behavior. what do you mean nested ? like when you check the source code of page you see them nested ? or visually ?

Comment: By habit I only using the single tag versions for BR and IMG, the rest I always have an opening and closing. Not sure why I do it but as I recall it  likely has something to do with old browser compatibility. I would think all modern browsers would be ok with it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` is not a valid self-closing tag in an HTML document. If you'd serve it as XHTML then it should work (if it doesn't, it's a browser bug).

You should also keep in mind that Doctype doesn't change how the document is interpreted, only mime-type (so it will work if you serve the document with Content-Type `application/xhtml+xml`) - you can read more here: http://www.webdevout.net/articles/beware-of-xhtml#content_type

Answer (score 0):

the problem is maybe caused by the browser going to quirk mode.

You can try adding a doctype